# Laravel whereDate user timezone

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

How do I query results in the users timezone?

All my users have a `timezone` attribute, e.g.:

`Auth::user()->timezone; // America/Toronto`

The app config timezone and the database timezone are set to UTC. Each user can have a different timezone. The problem is I'm trying to filter records for `today`, and its giving me results from yesterday as well:

`$query->whereDate($column, Carbon::now())`

I know this is because of the offset. I've tried using this which does not make a difference:

`$query->whereDate($column, Carbon::now()->tz(Auth::user()->timezone)`

How do I grab the correct results for the current day in the user timezone based on the database values using UTC?

Answer (score 1):

You could try adding a date range like this:

```
$query->whereDate($column, ">=", Carbon::now()->startOfDay()->tz(Auth::user()->timezone)
->whereDate($column, "<=", Carbon::now()->endOfDay()->tz(Auth::user()->timezone);
```

The key here would be determining the start and end of the current day using the default timezone, and then converting those timestamps to the current user's timezone.

I hope this helps!

Comment: This answer is the right one. Thanks @blessing :)